# Bills and Adjustment Screen AP301000 shows Inventory ID in Detail Section, yet no InventoryID property in BillDetail class

Tags: acumatica

Class BillDetail has no property InventoryID on a bill item level, yet there is a field Inventory ID in the grid, at least for Bills with for non-stock items.

How can I read/write this field using SOAP?

Thank you.
Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field becomes available to API if Endpoint is extended:

I went to a screen SM207060, extended endpoint and gave it a name.

Then I expanded the entity Bill->Bill Details, added a row and choose Document Details InventoryID-Inventory ID for the field, and saved.

Then I copied URL from view websource and changed reference in my VS project. The field Inventory ID became visible.